# What does Concurrency Diagram Menu in IntelliJ IDEA mean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA (15.0.5), on a class name, I see a window icon, clicking upon which brings up this popup menu:

[image]

Does anyone know what "Concurrency Diagram for [class name]" is supposed to do? When I actually select the menu item, it shows:

> Error running [class name]: Cannot find runner for
>   [class name].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Looks like](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/thread-concurrency-visualization.html) it's a Python specific feature. There seems to be [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147462) that when Cucumber is enabled for the project the menu option appears, even when it's not Python.